Full-Screen Notification Not Triggering as Expected in Android
We are attempting to implement a full-screen notification similar to an alarm clock, which triggers a full-screen activity. For this, we are utilizing the Full-Screen Intent in the NotificationCompat.Builder along with setting the Notification Priority to PRIORITY_HIGH. Despite these configurations, the full-screen notification is not appearing as expected.
Screenshots of output:
UI with Button
Notification
Code I used as below

// UI for Triggering the Notification
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun FullScreenNotificationExample(context: Context) {
    // Scaffold provides the basic layout structure, including a top bar
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            // TopAppBar displays the title at the top of the screen
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text("Full-Screen Notification") }
            )
        }
    ) {
        // Column arranges the button vertically and centers it
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize() // Make the column take up the entire screen
                .padding(it) // Account for Scaffold's inner padding
                .padding(16.dp), // Add additional padding around the content
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center // Center the button vertically
        ) {
            // Button to trigger the full-screen notification
            Button(
                onClick = { showFullScreenNotification(context) }, // Call the notification function when clicked
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth() // Make the button stretch across the width
            ) {
                Text(text = "Show Full-Screen Notification") // Display text inside the button
            }
        }
    }
}

// Function to create the notification channel (required for Android API 26+)
fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context, channelId: String) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { // Check if the device runs Android O or later
        // Define a notification channel with high importance
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            channelId,
            "Full-Screen Notifications", // User-visible name of the channel
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH // Ensures high priority notifications
        ).apply {
            description = "Channel for full-screen notifications" // Description shown in system settings
        }
        // Register the channel with the system
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}

// Function to build and display the full-screen notification
fun showFullScreenNotification(context: Context) {
    // Create the intent to launch the full-screen activity
    val fullScreenIntent = Intent(context, FullScreenActivity::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK // Ensure a fresh instance of the activity
    }

    // Create a pending intent that will launch the full-screen activity
    val fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context,
        0, // Request code (used to distinguish different PendingIntents)
        fullScreenIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE // Update existing PendingIntent for this intent and ensure immutability for API 29+
    )

    // Create a notification channel for the full-screen notification
    val channelId = "full_screen_notification_channel"
    createNotificationChannel(context, channelId)

    // Build the notification
    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info) // Set the notification's icon
        .setContentTitle("Full-Screen Notification") // Set the notification's title
        .setContentText("Urgent alert! This requires immediate attention.") // Set the notification's text
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH) // Make the notification high priority for immediate display
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM) // Classify the notification as an alarm for urgency
        .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true) // Attach the full-screen intent
        .build()

    // Display the notification
    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
        notify(1, notification) // Show the notification with an ID of 1
    }
}

// Manifest entry for the full-screen activity
<activity
    android:name=".NewActivity" // Specify the class name of the activity
    android:exported="true" // Allow other apps to launch this activity (necessary for intents)
    android:showOnLockScreen="true" // Ensure the activity is shown on the lock screen
    android:turnScreenOn="true"> // Ensure the screen turns on when the activity is displayed
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> // Specify this as a main entry point
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> // Allow the activity to appear in the launcher
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

